# Do something after user moves a marker

Tags: python

I'd like to update a list of markers [name,frame] everytime the user moves or deletes a marker. Yet, I couldn't find a solution using Handlers, but I have the feeling that it is possible...

The user's actions I'd like to monitor appear in the top info window.

**For example :**

> bpy.ops.marker.move(frames=-1512)

Any hint ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Waiting for a better solution, I update my list with a handlers.frame_change_post.... 25 times per seconds. That breaks my heart.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are no callbacks in `bpy.app.handlers` to catch these events. The api we have own isn't well suited to adding callbacks into 100's of operations which would be needed to support customizing the behavior of any tool.

Probably it would be better if we just have some way to update marker names built into Blender.

Comment: Wouldn't be possible to have a wordpress-like "hook" feature in the API ? You registrer a piece of code and hook it to any other pre-build function.

Comment: Its possible, but you really want a hook when any marker is moved (since there are multiple ways to do this), currently we just don't support that level of granuality.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your answer :-)